# haw to save the output of a script in a file ansible 2.0.2

Tags: linux, shell, yaml, ansible

i want to save the output of a command in a file , i tried to use :

```
- command: ./script1 >> file.txt 2>&1
```

but it's give me an empty file.
Is there any other method to save the output of my "script1" in a "file" using ansible 2.0.2 .
thank you in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `command` with `shell`.

> The [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOME` and operations like `"<"`, `">"`, `"|"`, and `"&"` will not work (use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html#shell) if you need these features).

Source: [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html).